# Advantages of maven war plugin instead of package?

Tags: maven

Are there any obvious advantages to using the Maven war plugin to build my war instead of just using `mvn clean package` with war set as the package type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the packaging to `war`, the standard build lifecycle calls the war plugin in the package phase, see also:

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

and search for `war:war`.